# How to convert json file into table structure in redshift using python

Tags: json, python-2.7, amazon-redshift

How can I convert JSON file into a table structure in Redshift? I tried the below python code.

```
import boto3
import json
import os
import sys
import psycopg2
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def jsonfile(path):
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id='dfjfkgj',
        aws_secret_access_key='sdfg',
        region_name='us-west-2')
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    bucket= s3.Bucket('ag-redshift-poc')
    with open(path, 'rb') as data:
        res=json.load(data)
        f = open('data.csv','wb')
        output = csv.writer(f) 
        output.writerow(res[0].keys())
        for row in res:
           output.writerow(row.values()) 


    bucket.put_object(Key=('C:\Python27\data.csv'),Body=res)
    print 'success'

def redshift():
    co=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'redshiftpoc', host='shdjf', 
    port= '5439', user= 'admin', password= 'snd')
    curr = co.cursor()
    curr.execute("""copy sample from 's3://ag-redshift-poc/testfile/json.txt'
                CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=fdfd;aws_secret_access_key=sxhd'
                """)
    co.commit()
    print 'success'
    curr.close()
    co.close()

jsonfile('C:\Python27\json.txt')
redshift()
```

Answer (score 3):

Redshift can directly absorb JSON to COPY into your table. (Though not very efficient).

In your case, modify the COPY query to,

```
COPY sample FROM 's3://<bucket_name>/<path_to_json>'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxx'
JSON 'auto' ACCEPTINVCHARS;
```

Please note `JSON 'auto'` in query. This maps every column in table with keys in JSON file.

More details here in the [COPY examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-copy-from-json)